# Firebase - React Website fails to read .env file

Tags: reactjs, firebase, deployment, environment-variables, hosting

I have two React websites with Firebase. I deployed the first one around 2 months ago and it's working perfectly.

Today, I deployed another website and it fails to read the `.env` file with environment variables.

Both websites have the same structure:

```
Root-Folder
|- .firebase
|- public
|- src
|- node_modules
|- .env
|- .firebaserc
|- firebase.json
|- package-lock.json
|- package.json
```

What could be the problem? I don't get any error on the website pages, it does load the pages, but it can't see the environment variables. For example I have the `<title>` in `.env`, but the website page just shows  `%REACT_APP_WEBSITE_TITLE%` instead.

Comment: Can you show how you are trying to display this title for instance ?

Comment: `<title>%REACT_APP_WEBSITE_TITLE% | Servizio Segnalazioni</title>` and `const baseURL = process.env.REACT_APP_API_URL;` for example in another file. But I'm using the same syntax in the other website and it's working fine there @TheTisiboth